# React Native Permissions not printing the status

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am using React Native version 42 and asking permissions as below. But after allowing or denying the permissions, I am not seeing the status in console. According to documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html they say we can see the status in console. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong. I want to print the status of granted but the line itself is not getting called.

```
componentDidMount() {       
this.requestPermissions();
}

async requestPermissions() {

    try {  
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        console.log("permissions status: " +JSON.stringify(granted));
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**PermissionAndroid.requestMultiple** returns a promise with permission status. Try like this

```
PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]).then((result) => {
  console.log('result', result);
})
```

Comment: Try pasting this directly in componentDidMount() and see if it works. Did you import PermissionAndroid from 'react-native'? What version of React native are you using?

Comment: Hell@Hariks can you give what u refer to use  link

Comment: I am using react-native-permissions module is it wroking for this?

Comment: This answer should work but you need to convert the result to a string to view it in the console i.e. `console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result));`